# Need to show td in same size, I want to remove image and need to place text instead

Tags: html

I have this working correctly with the image

```
 <td width="32%" valign="top"><img src="<?php echo $appConfigurations['url'];?>03.png" width="200" height="13" /></td>
```

When I put text instead of image, then its not showing me correctly I want exactly same size of td so that I can write text

```
 <td width="32%" valign="top" bgcolor="#4A4A4A"><span class="style1" style="display: block;"><?php echo "Hello !!!!";?></span></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should style the td with CSS. Try this:

```
<td valign="top" style="width:32%; height:13px; overflow:hidden; background-color:#4A4A4A;"> ..code ..</td>
```